# Plotting incomplete 3D data in contour plot

Tags: r, matlab, matplotlib, gnuplot, wolfram-mathematica

I have a set of incomplete 3D data. The data looks like the following:

```
X Y Z

1 1 3
1 2 4
1 3 5

2 2 8
2 3 7
2 4 1

3 1 0
3 4 3
```

Kindly note that the data is incomplete, since the data points with (1,4), (2,1), (3,2) and (3,3) is missing if I consider my X range as (1,2,3) and Y range as (1,2,3,4). Due to scientific reasons, the data is those points cannot be estimated.

As  a result the data cannot be made to a grid which is required by most of the programs for 3D plotting. However, I need to go for a contour plot of the same.

**Hence, can you kindly let me know of any software which will enable me to do the same, and also how to get it done? I would personally prefer a contour plot with colours. I do not mind leaving empty boxes in the plot, since my data is incomplete.**

Comment: Why so many code tags? It is generally advisable to stick to one specific language/framework. Code tag spamming will not lead to more answers.

Comment: @maurits-evers I would like you to note that this question does not pertain to a certain language. I just want a scientifically correct graph for my data, that's all. Hence, I have tagged languages which are mostly known for graphing, and that is not for greed of getting answers. **Solution in any programming language with graphing engine is welcome**.

P.S.: You seem to have a scientific background as visible from your profile, I hope you will understand my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mathematica**

```
data = {
   {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 5},
   {2, 2, 8}, {2, 3, 7}, {2, 4, 1},
   {3, 1, 0}, {3, 4, 3}
   };

ListContourPlot[data]
```

[image]